# Variable width stroke & anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

In Illustrator I have a heart shape and the last anchor point is on the upper left side (by that I mean the anchor point that joins everything together).

I would like to have a stroke that comes to a point at the bottom of the heart shape and is thick at the top of the heart shape.

To do this I thought I'd give the 'Variable Width Profile" for strokes a go... but it finishes at the last / joining point at the upper top left which looks a bit crap.

[image]

Is there a way I can get it to finish at the base of the heart shape?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is unnecessary but what does your path look like (as in when you select it)? Is it all one path? Are there 4 points? etc. (Screenshot may be helpful)

Comment: Added. I think it's all one line yea.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some mileage out of the `Width Tool`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. With this, you can set the width of a stroke manually instead of being dependent on a width profile.

Answer (score 0):

It May be the one reason, that your starting point of shape resides there so you are getting such effect. It may give your desired effect if you start the shape creation where you need the thinner effect.

Comment: Yea, that is what I had to do in the end just wondered if there was a shortcut. 
Thanks

Comment: You can shift the stroke points also...